# Fetch Basic Authorization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my syntax for this fetch statement?

```
fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(this.props.api_key + ":" + password),
    },
})
```

When I do not include the headers portion, I get a 401 error which is expected as this external API requires an API key. When I add the headers, the fetch statement does not even seem to run. I have `console.log()` statements within promises for the function to see if I get a response back. There is no error reported or anything so I am assuming it must be some sort of syntax error that is stopping fetch from functioning properly.

Comment: What do you see in the network tab?

Answer (score 0):

[Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) is async; it returns a Promise. You can use `await fetch(...)` to use it in a synchronous style method, or use the Promise chain:

```
fetch(url, headers).then(response => {
  // do something with the response
})
```